# To generate Full stream operation history report using rtc plain java api

Tags: java, rational-team-concert

I am trying to implement a functionality using which i can generate the full stream operation history report.
Here is my existing code :

'''
IWorkspaceSearchCriteria wsSearchCriteria = IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();

```
 wsSearchCriteria.setKind(IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.STREAMS);



      List<IWorkspaceHandle> workspaceHandles = workspaceMgr.findWorkspaces(wsSearchCriteria, Integer.MAX_VALUE, null);

      for (IWorkspaceHandle wksHandle : workspaceHandles)

      {

          stream = workspaceMgr.getWorkspaceConnection(wksHandle, null);



          System.out.println(stream);

      }
```

'''
Please also let me know if the raised question is ambiguous
Thanks in advance